# issues with C Program to convert user input to Integer and then Integer to (HEX, Bin, Alpha)

Tags: c, integer, hex, ascii, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

/*holds the number to be converted between methods.*/
char convNumber;

/*storageInt */
int storageInt;

    puts("put text in here to convert to bin");
    while ((convNumber = getchar()) != '$') {

        storageInt = storageInt * 100 + convNumber;

    }

     printf("%d", &storageInt);

    return 0;
}
```

ok, Above is the code that is giving me problems. I'm new to C and this is a school project.

Question:
How do i convert user input with a delimiting character '$' into an integer which I can store and print or use to convert to hex or binary. At the bottom of the page is a full view of what my output should eventually look like to give an idea of the type of input required.

Background and assignment info:

I keep getting unexpected output when attempting to print the user input as an integer. My goal is to have blocks of 2 integers, representing ASCII, in order from 0 to N (N is the end of user input). User input is designated as finished by typing $. What am I doing wrong?

When going through the program choosing "A", "A", and then finally "A$" ($ for terminating the program) I get 2337412 instead of the expected 65 ascii for 'A'.

So please help me understand this so I will do better on subsequent assignments (looking for explanations). Thanks in advance!

END RESULT:

> Welcome to the Coder!
>   Choose Input (H,A,B,Q): A
>   Choose Output(H,A,B): H
>   Enter your alpha input.
>   Hi! Bye! $
>   486921204279652120
>   Choose Input (H,A,B,Q): H
>   Choose Output(H,A,B): B
>   Enter your hex input.
>   486921204279652120$
>   010010000110100100100001001000000100001001111001011001010010000100100000
>   Choose Input (H,A,B,Q): B
>   Choose Output(H,A,B): A
>   Enter your bin input.

Comment: "_I will redact this to prevent copy and paste._" - you won't be allowed to do that. SO is meant to be a repository of Q&As that will help people with the same problem down the line. If you do not want this content to be publicly available, don't post it at all. (And there is a full, public, editing history on all posts, so "redacting" is completely useless.)

Comment: It's not that I don't want it publicly available, I was going to redact it to prevent cheating next quarter in this class. If I'm not able to make changes then it is what it is. 

Anyway, it doesn't change the fact that I'm stuck and need some help moving along. If you wish to help me then I would appreciate any suggestion or pointers.

Comment: If you want help here, your should start by narrowing down your issue. All the code you posted regarding input/output select is irrelevant. Strip it all out, keep the minimal core (read text, convert to number), and describe exactly what's going wrong with that. Should be ~10-15 lines of code and about that much description. Make sure the resulting snippet builds with no warnings, including when you include optimizations (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2` as a minimum for gcc or clang).

Comment: I'll reduce it. Currently I have no warnings. My direct question, which I will update, is how to convert user input with a delimiting character '$' into an integer which I can store and print or use to convert to hex or binary.

Comment: Reduced down. Do you have any direction or anything I should put special attention to?

Comment: Doesn't pass the "compiles without warnings" test with gcc or clang. Extra hint: what is the initial value of `storageInt`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: roger, I thought you meant the main program. The snippet compiles without error now. My assumption is that storageInt is automatically left as null. Further up I had it set to 0.

I will read your link as well. thank you.

Comment: Initializing storageInt to 0 still provides unexpected input. Though I found that if I put a leading zero in  scanf(" %[^$]%*c", &convNumber); I get more expected results. However, it prints them out of order. with the first ascii number in the output staying in positions 1 and 10 and each subsequent character being added to the next points, such as 100 and 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing `storageInt`'s memory address. You use memory addresses only in scanf for reasons you'll find obvious after you learn more. Strings are an exception, but this is not a string.

Do this:

```
printf("%d", storageInt);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks

Comment: By the way, when do you actually initialize storageInt? Its starting value can literally be any. You should set it to something right in declaration.

Comment: I have fixed the initialization of storageInt and fixed the printF call. It now creates something more consistent.